# Linq Get Data Based On Single Column Value

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda

I want to get the job count based on gender by relation database.

1st Table - Persons

```
PersonID  PersonName Gender
1         Anand      Male
2         sam        Male
3         Mary       Female
```

2nd Table - Jobs

```
JobID    Job     PersonID
1        x        1
2        y        3
3        z        1
4        a        2
```

Required output

```
Gender   JobCount
Male     3
Female   1
```

My model

```
public class value
{
    public string Gender {get;set;}
    public int JobCount {get;set;}
}
```

My code

```
var data = from t1 in db.Persons
          join t2 in db.Jobs on t1.PersonID equals t2.PersonID into PersonJob
          select new value { Gender = t1.Gender , JobCount = PersonJob.Count()};
```

but it doesn't give the required output.

Comment: Yeah but here is a different scenario

Comment: How would you have solved this with SQL? Start there and then see how to convert it to Linq.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer

```
var orders = from t1 in db.Persons
             join t2 in db.Jobs on t1.PersonID equals t2.PersonID
             group t1.Gender by t1.Gender into data
             select new value { Gender = data.Key , JobCount = data.Count()};
```

By the above i got the required o/p